# Why Check_MK service showing status details as null?

Tags: nagios, check-mk

I am using Check_MK version 1.2.0p2.

On Check_MK UI I am getting (null ) as a status details for service Check_MK.

Here is the image for more clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the precompiled check for that hosts, then "check_mk -II " and then "check_mk -R". That did it for me! (I am using OMD)

Comment: Hi Marco,

I am using nagios with OMD. I have added Windows 2008 R2 hosts using WATO on nagios UI. The check_mk_agent is installed on Windows 2008 R2 hosts. While inventorying the services from that host I am getting following error.

Cannot get data from TCP port xxx.xx.xxx.xx:6556: (111, 'Connection refused')

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I had a problem with MikroTik router yielding `(null)` status and while re-inventory (with `cmk -II hostname`) by itself didn't work, removing precompiled checks and then running the re-inventory worked fine. Thanks :)